# for in, how to limit the output?

Tags: javascript

For my Javascript course I got this code:

```
for (var i in window.navigator)
{ 
    document.getElementById('divResult').innerHTML +=
        i  + ': ' + window.navigator[i] + '<br />';
}
</script>
```

The teacher (online) wants me to limit the results into maximal 10.

For me this is a big puzzle. From other questions about the for..in I think to know it is a discussable statement. But how to approach this for..in? As an array with i.length?

Comment: I'm confused. He wants the first 10 results?

Comment: The first 10 results will be good.

Comment: The answer below is good then

Answer (score 1):

Just set a counter. In each iteration you increase the counter and when the counter reaches 10 you simply break out of your loop

Code:

```
// Since we're going to access this div multiple times it's best to
// store it outside of the for loop.
var output = document.getElementById('divResult');

var counter = 0;
for (var elem in window.navigator) {
    var value = window.navigator[elem];

    output.innerHTML += counter + ': ' + elem + '=' + value + '<br />';

    ++counter;
    if (counter == 10) {
        break;
    }
}
```

**Since you're new to JavaScript I would like to explain a little bit about for-in**

If you want to get a specific value from an array you access it's element by index. So for example:

```
var myArray = [7, 5, 6, 6];
for (var i = 0; i < myArray.length; ++i) {
    var value = myArray[i];
}
```

But now you want to loop through `window.navigator` and this element is not an array but a object. And since a object is key-value it does not have a index. So how do you loop through it?

Let's imagine window.navigator looks like this:

```
var navigator = {
    myBrowser: 'Google Chrome',
    myOtherProperty: 'otherValue',
    AnotherProperty: 'anotherValue'
};
```

If we want to get the first element from our object we use

```
navigator.myBrowser
```

or

```
navigator['myBrowser'];
```

Now we want to loop through all the elements in our object. Since the normal `for` loop uses a index and objects don't have indexes we use the `for in` loop. This loop iterates through all the properties of our object and gives us the key.

```
for (var key in navigator) {
    // Here we access a property in our object by the key given by our for loop.
    var value = navigator[key];
}
```

So the first iteration our key is `myBrowser` and the value is `Google Chrome`
The next iteration the key is `myOtherProperty` and the value `otherValue`.

It is usually a good idea to use [hasOwnProperty](https://developer.mozilla.org/nl/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty) if you're looping through an object:

```
for (var key in navigator) {
    if (navigator.hasOwnProperty(key) {
        var value = navigator[key];
    }
}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I don ´t know what variable to ues to get it on screen: counter[i]? Or? How or where are counter and i connected?

Comment: You want to print the counter or do you want to print the elements you're looping through?

Answer (score 0):

The teacher came back with an answer for my for..in array problem:

```
<script>
    var navigatorArray = [];
for (var i in  window.navigator) {              
    navigatorArray.push(window.navigator[i]);  
}
navigatorArray.sort();
console.log(navigatorArray);

var htmlString = '';   
for (var j = 0; j < navigatorArray.length; j++) {
    htmlString += navigatorArray[j] + '<br />'; 
}
```

with the .push habbit it should be possible to collect them in an array and index them.